# How do I make a render appear in the compositor with Nodes?

Tags: rendering, node-editor

I am following a tutorial and can´t find a way to do it. So how do I make a render appear in the compositor with Nodes?

[image: nodes]

This is my setup. I want my render to appear in the background.
Any ideas?

Comment: click on the "backdrop" button (upper right corner of the view)

Comment: how does that button look like? Is it visible in my image?

Comment: yes, it is under rendering and compositing, or two buttons right from your pin of your main view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In recent versions of Blender you need to enable backdrop *and* add a Viewer node. You also won't see anything until you've rendered a frame.

To enable backdrop, click the *backdrop* button in the compositor header:

[image: backdrop button]

Here is a simple compositor setup I use as a starting point:

[image: Compositor set up]

I've drawn a red box around the Viewer node, to highlight it.  You don't need a frame. You can ignore the Denoiser node.  You just replace it with the setup from your tutorial.

Notice that there's no image in either the Render layers node, or the backdrop.  When I render a frame that changes:

[image: Same setup showing backdrop with render]

Comment: I found the backdrop button in the Animation section, not Compositing. Why is that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, unless your window is narrow enough that the button is hidden to the right.  Have you tried scrolling the Compositor editor window's header to see if that's the case?